# Grammar quine - Formal grammar self-definition

Tags: formal-grammars

Is it possible to derive a grammar with iself?
Or more precisely, is it possible to conceive a grammar which language contains that grammar?

For example, the Wikipedia article about BNF claims to represent the [BNF syntax with BNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form#Further_examples).
But if we tried to derive BNF with it, we'd obtain the same BNF, but with each character quoted (double-quotes single-quoted and other characters double-quoted). It's understandable, but it's not exactly the same (actually it's like if the quoted characters were another alphabet).

Here is my attempt to define an unrestricted grammar (ignore white spaces):

- P = p P | p ;
- p = V n V **=** A **;** ;
- A = V **|** A | V ;
- V = v V | ;
- v = n | t ;
- n = **P** | **p** | **V** | **v** | **n** | **t** ;
- t = `P` | `p` | `V` | `v` | `n` | `t` | `=` | `|` | `;` ;

Another one with less "special characters" (|, A, p, v, n and t are optional but improved readability):

- P = V **P** V **=** V **;** P ;
- P = V **V** V **=** V **;** P ;
- P = V **P** V **=** V **;** ;
- P = V **V** V **=** V **;** ;
- V = **P** V ;
- V = **V** V ;
- V = `P` V ;
- V = `V` V ;
- V = `=` V ;
- V = `;` V ;
- V = ;

And with a regex: ( [ **P** **V** `P` `V` `=` `;` ]* [ **P** **V** ] [ **P** **V** `P` `V` `=` `;` ]* **=** [ **P** **V** `P` `V` `=` `;` ]* **;** )+

So we need 3 alphabets to build it (normal for "special characters", **bold** for variables and `code` for terminals).

EDIT: Actually we need an infinite number of alphabet... If we try to derive it once, normal is replaced by **bold**, **bold** by `code`, but we need a new alphabet to replace `code`…

Is it possible to derive it with only one alphabet?

---

EDIT: A question I'll ask in another post:

Is it possible to design a program able to learn a grammar with just its self-definition?

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  What does "build a grammar with iself" mean?  Can you give us a much smaller (minimal) example?  That example is a lot to wade through.  Also, please ask only one question per post (you can ask about building a program separately; but first please do a little research to read about grammar induction).

Comment: No, it's not possible, because the symbols $\to$, $\epsilon$ and $|$ cannot appear in $\Sigma$.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Why not?

Comment: @Raphael How will you tell, e.g.,  whether $S\to A|B$ means "expand $S$ to either $A$ or $B$" or "expand $S$ to the string $A$-pipe-$B$"? If you do it by replacing those symbols with something different, then the string you generate isn't the grammar you started with.

Comment: Well, what about a context-free grammar (no ambiguity with $\to$) without $\epsilon$ or $|$ which are optional (like in my second attempt)?

Comment: @DavidRicherby That's a problem of human reader, not of mathematical semantics. I see no problem at all with using the same symbols. CYK, say, does not care with which notation the grammar was written down at some point.

Comment: The more interesting question here is this. We know that TM-equivalent models have quines; so there should be unrestricted grammar quines (cc @DavidRicherby). But do NPDA-equivalent models have quines?

Comment: @Raphael It's absolutely a problem of mathematical semantics. In just the same way that it's a problem of mathematical semantics if you have a variable called $+$ and you can't tell whether the string $x+y$ means the sum of $x$ and $y$ or the product of $x$, $+$ and $y$. Mathematical expressions are supposed to have unique parsings: if they don't, their meaning is undefined.

Comment: @DavidRicherby But we don't have to read a mixed string here. Anyway, by your reasoning there couldn't be *any* quine?

Comment: @Raphael Programming languages get around the problem by having  strings that can contain arbitrary characters, and having ways of getting around the ambiguity of a string literal such as `" " " "` (the literal string quote-quote, or two empty strings next to each other?) such as escapes and mechanisms to insert arbitrary characters into strings.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Idiosyncracies of programming languages are not necessary to prove the existence of quines; plain old recursion theory is more than sufficient. And we simply don't care that we use numbers to derive that a particular number can be accepted/output. (See also [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/33829/98).)

Comment: @DavidRicherby  Anyway, formal grammars get around that as well. The symbol "$\to$" just has different meaning as part of the "meta-language" we use to write down a grammar, and as part of the terminal alphabet of that same grammar. You can label them to keep them apart in writing down the grammar, but that doesn't change the semantics here.